# "BAD idea" warning when trying to recover Grub, after Windows removed it

Tags: 10.10, grub2, dual-boot

Tried sudo grub-install on sda1 but it complained about being a BAD IDEA.

I had to install windows for a work related issue so I used a separate disk (I had used it for ubuntu on this computer, but bought a bigger disk so installed ubuntu on that and left the old one in in case I needed an old file). Windows installed fine but overwrote Grub. So if I choose the Ubuntu disk to boot first in BIOS I get a blank screen.

I googled and followed this advice:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

However, when I get down to this section:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/0d104aff-ec8c-44c8-b811-92b993823444 /dev/sda1
```

I get this:

```
Attempting to install GRUB to a partition instead of the MBR. This is a BAD idea…
```

--recheck does nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *bad idea* warning is caused by trying to install grub onto a **partition** rather than a **hard disk**. Having booted up your Live CD,

- when you run grub-install as per the [Guide in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows), make sure the hard drive you pass as an argument is `/dev/sda`, not `/dev/sda1`.

  That is:

  ```
  sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/[GUID] /dev/sda
  ```

  Where [GUID] is the identifier of the disk you have found out using `mount | tail -1`

Here's why:

- The master boot record, MBR, is the first 512 byte 'sector' of any partitioned
  hard disk.

  - The BIOS searches this sector when trying to find a device it can
    boot from.

  In the GNU/Linux system, your hard disks are all named `/dev/sd[x]`, where x
  are consecutive letters. E.g.: `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. The first **partition** on the first disk is called `/dev/sda1`. The fourth partition on the seventh hard disk is called `/dev/sdg4`, and so on. At the very least, you'll have one partition.
- These partitions are not searched for bootable data by
  the bios.
  As a result, `grub-install [...] /dev/sda7` will issue a warning. You *can* install
  it there, but in almost any case, you shouldn't.

Comment: Worked perfectly; can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not smart of me to ask this on a very old question, but why exactly is it bad to install grub on a partition? I read some tutorials where they prefer doing it that way, and then use the windows boat loader, and let it point to that boot partition.

Comment: @gl3nn that sounds like it would work. I guess grub wants to be first. :)