# What do I select for "GRUB install devices" after an update?

Tags: grub2, update-manager, mbr, debconf

After running Update Manager, a debconf window  (titled "Configuring grub-pc"), popped up, requiring me to select the appropriate`GRUB install devices` for my system.  I've made no changes to grub or the filesystem recently, and I don't remember what options I selected last time I did make a change.

How do I know what to select?  I'm assuming the wrong answer could render my system unable to boot.

Here's the debconf dialog:

[image: Debconf window, configuring grub-pc, containing check-boxes for /dev/sda and /dev/sda1]

Here's the window and text that is displayed when selecting "help" :

[image: Grub was previously installed to a disk that is no longer present]

Comment: This dialog also crops up when upgrading a virtualbox vm's ubuntu version (in my case, 10.10 -> 11.04).

Comment: As far as my experience with this, it looks like a usability bug. I have run updates countless times and whenever this dialog pops up, I click nothing in the first dialog and then confirm that I want to continue without installing grub. Never had a problem so far. I guess it is because grub is already installed in the proper MBR otherwise the machine would not have booted in the first place.

Comment: wtf is that ? I just wanted to update a few package as it was suggesting, now I need to make a choice that might kill my system... such bad bad bad stuff !!

Comment: **This is a terrifying experience!** I just had it while simply doing an apt upgrade on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (running inside a VirtualBox VM on a Windows 10 host which just got restarted due to updates, I thought it messed everything up) -- nevertheless it worked after choosing `/dev/sda`

Comment: Ran into this. Google sent me here. My Linux guru said: run `lsblk`, the drive that has the `/` mountpoint (root) is the boot disk. It may be a partition (ending in a number like sda1). Use this partition's disk (by removing the number, /dev/sda in this case). If you left the menus and are unsure if you wrecked your system, run `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`. I took all the defaults and selected the disk that had the root-partition on. The system rebooted okay.

Comment: This bad UX experience can still be had in Ubuntu 22.04.3

From my `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

`grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64 (2.06-2ubuntu14.1, 2.06-2ubuntu14.4)`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In your case, the correct selection is **`/dev/sda`**, the first one. It's the first and only hard disk in your system, whereas `/dev/sda1` is a partition on that hard disk. You *can* install grub on a partition, but it's [a "BAD idea"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19704/bad-idea-warning-when-trying-to-recover-grub-after-windows-removed-it).

If you had multiple hard drives and partitions, first find out where your root partition is:

```
lsblk
```

(See also: [How do I find out what hard disks are in the system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/how-do-i-find-out-what-hard-disks-are-in-the-system))

You can then install grub on that hard drive. Look for devices labeled "disk" (e.g. "sda", meaning `/dev/sda`) to install grub into the master boot record (every physical disk device has only one MBR, no matter the partitions).

Comment: To finish off the story (which has ended well enough): I selected /dev/sda as suggested.  On the next window, I was asked if I wanted to continue without installing grub.  Odd, of course, since I had just asked to install it.  There was a checkbox to mark to continue without installing, or, if I pressed the "Forward" button, it went *back* to the previous screen, asking where I wanted to install grub. Instead of looping forever, I checked the box, told it not to install grub and crossed my fingers.  On reboot, there were no problems. It remains perplexing why this interaction was required.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo  So what causes the install/don't install loop?  I just had the same experience in 12.04.

Comment: I just had the same issue on 14.04. I would say this was a bug, if not in code then in usability.

Comment: Just got the same thing on 14.04. I think the purpose of the dialog was to ask you whether you would like to install Grub on any other drive, other than the one it is currently installed on, and thus showed you the "Continue without install" option. I am not totally sure about this, though.

Comment: Note that `df` is likely to return a label now a day. You may want to do an edit to update that part (i.e. how do you know which hard drive the label links to?)

Comment: Thanks @AlexisWilke, I've updated the answer (lsblk is nicer). However, I have never seen `df` return labels. How do I get it to do this?

Comment: When I install a computer with LVM, it puts partitions on things that `df` shows as `/dev/mapper/<name>` where `<name>` is the *label* for that device. For example, I created a VPS with VirtualBox and my root partition is on `/dev/mapper/snap--vg-root`.

Comment: Thank makes sense @AlexisWilke. I don't have a system with lvm to hand. Can you confirm that the output of `lsblk` is helpful here?

Comment: Yes. `lsblk` includes the mount point which means it will include `"/"` and the device name (opposed to the label). Although it will be something like `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/md1` which means the user still need to understand that he has to ignore the `1` (or whatever other number.)

Comment: In my case, the install/don't install loop was caused by me _not actually selecting a drive_.  I would move the selection bar to what I'd want, and then hit Enter.  I was supposed to hit space bar first, making an asterisk appear in front of the selection.  After I'd done _that_, it counted as 'selected' and would let me out of the loop.

Answer (score 36):

This issue was still present when I upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 after a fresh install. To fix it, do this:

- The selection of `/dev/sda` is correct, so press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> for the first option.
- An asterisk appears for the `/dev/sda` option, signifying successful selection.
- Then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to highlight the 'OK' button and then press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key to select the OK action.

After this, the installation should proceed smoothly.

Comment: This is only if it shows a "Bash menu" or [dialog](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) not in the example of the question with Ubuntu DE where you have a GUI and can click the checkbox with the mouse pointer.

Comment: yeah ... this grub bug is still happening today even on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 20.04 and on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop ... here is a writeup on the current security grub bug "Grub2 security update renders system unbootable - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23999212 "