# What option do I choose for this update?

Tags: updates

My Ubuntu software thingy asked me to update, then presented me with this intimidating choice.  Which one is correct?  Why is it asking me this?

[image]

Comment: That's strange at least the second window behind the updater I would not choose anything and let the updater do its thing. Can you fully update your systen? When I update my system I see a windows similar to this but it flashes so quickly I couldn't swear it's the same window with these options. I would do nothing at this point

Comment: I can't cancel & and it requires me to choose an option before continuing.

Comment: Does this second windows appear each time you try to update your system I've never see this before

Comment: I don't know. I can't proceed until I pick one. But it hasn't happened before.

Comment: Take a look at this post I manages to find it may help you to decide how to move pass this window http://askubuntu.com/questions/23418/what-do-i-select-for-grub-install-devices-after-an-update