# Lubuntu 20.04 - Error configuring shim-signed - GRUB install devices on update

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, grub-efi

I used to have both a Windows 10 disk and another with Lubuntu, but now I left the Lubuntu as the main disk, and removed the other one. I was updating and the following message appears:
[image]

I selected the drive and clicked "Continue", which leads me to this:

[image]

But i clicked "No" because I don't want to continue if boot might fail afterwards, but doing that takes me back to the first picture. So I am not sure how to proceed to avoid boot problems.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @guiverc Unless Lubuntu now uses the Debian logo, this is Debian.

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 LTS @guiverc

Comment: @nico_so For any dual-boot with Windows disabling the latter's Fast Startup is a must.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Do you mean when installing? Because that was some time ago, I think I need to re-configure boot with only the Lubuntu disk, but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Again, not Lubuntu therefore off-topic here. You can and should disable that Windows fake feature anytime.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  fyi:  I've seen debian logos in a number of Lubuntu packages (I'm a Lubuntu member; those we use straight from upstream Debian esp. LXDE or now EOL) but not one in many cycles..  I'm exploring to verify

Comment: Likely helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/23418/what-do-i-select-for-grub-install-devices-after-an-update     If I may ask, what command (or tool) did you use to upgrade your system?   (I did get a debian logo to appear)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I select for "GRUB install devices" after an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23418/what-do-i-select-for-grub-install-devices-after-an-update)

Comment: Hi, thanks! Yes, I ended up checking "Yes" box and it just worked. I've read the comments on the suggested question and he just did that hoping it would work. It did. Thank you. @guiverc

Comment: Glad you got it solved :)